# Data Type Mismatch during using SSIS to import data to HANA

Tags: sql-server, time, ssis, hana

I am trying to import data from SQL Server to SAP HANA using SSIS package. I am facing the following hurdle :

- An input source column has data type time(0)
- Corresponding column in HANA has data type time, which is stored as 'secondtime' in column data type.
- Now, while executing the control flow task (moving data from source to destination using ODBC connectors) time(0) is somehow interpreted as 'binary' source and hence an error is thrown saying mismatching column types.

What should be the appropriate destination column type to correct the issue? TIA

Following is the stack trace :

> SSIS package "c:\users\shubha\documents\visual studio 2015 
> \Projects\SAPHANA\SAPHANA\Package.dtsx" starting. 
> Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation 
> phase is beginning. 
> Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation 
> phase is beginning. 
> Warning: 0x80049304 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Warning: Could 
> not open global shared memory to communicate with performance DLL; 
> data flow performance counters are not available.  To resolve, run 
> this package as an administrator, or on the system's console. 
> Information: 0x40043006 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for 
> Execute phase is beginning. 
> Information: 0x40043007 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute 
> phase is beginning. 
> Information: 0x4004300C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Execute 
> phase is beginning. 
> Error: 0x384 at Data Flow Task, ODBC Destination [2]: Open Database 
> Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. SQLExecute returned error while 
> inserting row 1 
> Error: 0x384 at Data Flow Task, ODBC Destination [2]: Open Database   
> Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: 'S1000'. Native Error Code: 
> -10404. [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB32 DLL][HDBODBC32] General error;-10404 
> Conversion not supported for parameter/column (5), source type BINARY 
> and target type SECONDTIME 
> Error: 0x384 at Data Flow Task, ODBC Destination [2]: Open Database 
> Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: 'S1000'. Native Error Code: 
> -10404. [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB32 DLL][HDBODBC32] General error;-10404 Conversion not supported for parameter/column (5), source type BINARY and target type SECONDTIME 
> Error: 0x384 at Data Flow Task, ODBC Destination [2]: Open Database 
> Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: 'S1000'. Native Error 
> Code: -10512. [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB32 DLL][HDBODBC32] General  
> error;-10512 Row not processed due to previous error

Comment: When you define source as table name, can you change it to sql command, use select statement to convert time(0) to varchar(8). See what outcome might be.

Comment: When the table is imported into SSIS using ODBC Adapter, the column that has data type of time in MSSQL is read as binary by ODBC adapter, and hence cast is not working. May be its an issue with ODBC adapter itself (backward Compatibility) though it shouldn't be.

Comment: Source connection can use OLEDB provider for SQL Server, while the destination can use whatever works on HANA. Why must be ODBC for SQL Server?